# 1 to 1 Comparison and Ranking System

Tags: php, mysql, math

I'm looking to create a comparison and ranking system which allows users to view 2 items, click on the one that they feel is the better one and then get presented with 2 more random items and continue to do this until they decide to stop.

In the background, I want the system to use these wins and loses to rank each item in an overall ranking table so I can then see what is #1 and what isn't.

I haven't got a clue where to begin with the formula, but I image I need to log wins and loses.

Any help/direction appreciated!

Comment: You might want to look at [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394466/hot-or-not-facemash-algorithm-why-elos-rating-algo).

Comment: There's quite a nice explanation of the Elo Rating equation here: http://onemoredigit.com/post/1327957577/the-social-network-elo-rating-equation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use the Elo algorithm!**

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system):

> The Elo rating system is a method for calculating the relative skill levels of players in two-player games such as chess. It is named after its creator Arpad Elo, a Hungarian-born American physics professor.

It is actually used in many areas, not only games, as you can [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system#Applications_apart_from_gaming).

The general idea is, each person has a number. The higher the number, the better the player, and vice-versa. The winning person would gain a certain amount of points, and the losing person would lose *the same amount* of points. This amount is decided by the difference in rating between two competitors. The mathematical details can [also be found on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system#Mathematical_details).

This sounds to be exactly what you need to implement. Just a couple of notes:

- Yes, you should log wins-losses.
- No, you should not keep track of streaks.

Comment: I was thinking of the [Schulze Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulze_method) or any other [Condorcet method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_method) instead, but in this particular situation, perhaps the Elo system would do as there's a clean winner and a clean loser on each pair (and it was also used in facebook's origin, facemash)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm over simplifying, but couldn't you just create a new database table called "ranks" foreign-keyed to the item?  Then, everytime a rank is set, just run this:

```
update `rank` set rankUp = rankUp + 1 where rankId = $whateverYourItemIdWouldBe
```

Then, checking the highest value would be as simple as:

```
select * from `items` left join `rank` on items.itemId = ranks.itemId order by ranks.rankUp desc
```